# verb+ing about verb+ing about

Tags: sentence-structure

> 1. I was thinking about talking about (something)

Is this structure correct? It does seem awkward but I don't see anything in this sentence for it to be grammatically wrong. And how about this:

> 2. I was talking about talking about (something)

If I was talking about a `specific thing` one week ago and I just talked about how and what I was talking that day yesterday, so now I am telling one of my friends that yesterday I was talking about talking about (`that thing`). Is this grammatically correct?

For example;

> 1st.December.2020- A famous group was `talking about` disbanding(within themselves)
>
> 7th.December.2020- They revealed it to the public that they were `talking about` disbanding.(They didn't actually as they decided not to)
>
> 10th.December.2020- I see someone rewatching the video of them of 7th.December and I asked him **"3. Isn't it where the band was `talking about` `talking about` disbandment"** because in that video itself they are not talking about disbanding they just said they were talking about it.

Comment: Yes - that's **exactly** what people say!  "The band was talking about talking about disbanding". (We would usually say "disbanding", not "disbandment".) And if we are at a party and it is late but we are having fun, we might say we are thinking about thinking about leaving.

Comment: Thank you very much @OldBrixtonian

Comment: I certainly wouldn't say anything like that! They are grammatical, but sound very awkward. I would say something like "I was talking about our conversation about..." or "I was telling her about talking about...".

Comment: In a formal context I agree it would sound awkward, and I certainly should have said so. But informally, a repeat may sound more natural than the avoidance of one. "He's an interior designer's interior designer" is certainly a tedious construction, but "I'm thinking of thinking of leaving" is brief and mildly playful. Playfulness itself can be amusing or irritating, but it seems to be a characteristic of BrE.